# create calculated last year date on selected month only in powerbi

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have data column name "Loss Date" I want to create new column "Policy Date" based on this column and the condition is if Month<4 then display last year date otherwise not. actually, I want to create Policy Date column and I want to display in this bar chart which is given below,
can anybody helps me regarding this in PowerBI?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In **Power Query Editor**, add a custom column with this below code-

```
=if Date.Month([loss date]) < 5 then "Apr-"& Text.From(Date.Year([loss date]) - 1) &" to Mar-"& Text.From(Date.Year([loss date]))  else "Apr-"& Text.From(Date.Year([loss date])) &" to Mar-"& Text.From(Date.Year([loss date]) +1)
```

Here is the output-

[image]

**Now** you can use that new column to your chart for generating Bars.